# What is it called when you use object... as a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays

I have noticed in Java that you can have a function with object... as a parameter and then method will take any number of objects as a parameter and treat it as an array. What is this called? I have been trying to search for it but it seems ... is ignored by search engines.
I seem to remember printf in C does the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia says this is called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Answer (score 2):

It's called varargs

Answer (score 1):

It's called varargs.

It means is function is accepting variable number of arguments. In C/CPP there is a header file stdarg.h which have declaration of methods for handling variable arguments.