# What is meant by methodName(Params... params) in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is it called when you use object… as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397895/what-is-it-called-when-you-use-object-as-a-parameter)

I'm seeing this kind of pattern a lot in Java. My question is, what is the `...` for, and what's it called?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397895/what-is-it-called-when-you-use-object-as-a-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "varargs":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

It's a feature of Java 1.5+ and has been around for nearly a decade.

Comment: It's also called "variable arity" in the Java Language Specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1

Answer (score 1):

OK...

(Params... params)

"..." means **variable length of parameters**.

Moreover doInBackground a method to do the process intensive work in non-ui thread, present in `SwingWorker class Java`, and in `AsyncTask<> in Android`.