# How to make parameters not care?

Tags: java

So I made a class that all it does is `print(System.out.println(""))` but when I make the method  I have to have a parameter ie. `public static void theprinter(String a){}`.So I was wondering if there was a way to make the parameter not care what it was given instead it would give it to the `System.out.println();` parameter no matter what it is given.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printer PrinterWorkerObject = new printer();
        PrinterWorkerObject.theprinter("this is the only string i can print");
    }
}

public class printer {
    public static void theprinter(String a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it not care about what? Just print out everything it receives?

Comment: What you mean with this: "parameter not care what it was given"?? Is it if you pass it or not?

Comment: Your `theprinter` method looks OK to me:  it takes whatever string it's given, doesn't matter what it is, and prints it to `System.out`.  It's not clear what you think the problem is.

Comment: simple use the `@Apathetic` annotation on them!

Comment: I think he means to do something like the javascript {printer.theprinter = System.out.println;} which is impossible in Java.

Comment: Are you looking for [variadic functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1397895/10077), perhaps?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson can't believe I just searched for that on spring.io, lol

Answer (score 3):

#### Short Answer:

```
public class Printer 
{
    public static void print(final Object o)
    {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

#### Comments:

Learn the Java Style guide, `ClassNames` are UpperCamelCase, `methodNames` are lowerCamelCase for starters.

Methods should be single `verbs`, Classes should be single `nouns`.

Comment: yes I know the camel casing style, I just throw this together because I didn't want to put my entire project in the posting box. Thank you though.

Comment: How much effort you put into your questions is how much effort others will put into their answers, sloppy questions aren't going to inspire as many people to help because they don't see the care or concern from you. So you kind of admit to being lazy, which is exactly what the sloppyness of this question conveys.

Comment: will it handle the primitive types ???

Comment: Well Jarrod, I am soooo sorry for wasting your time. Thank you for the help and the huge confidence boost! I hope to talk to you some other time.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(anyObject)` it will print everythin.the toString() method of the object wil be called and resultant string wil be printed so dont care for any parameter passing to it